# Magento product images messed up

Tags: image, caching, magento, product

I run magento and host 2 stores, for simplicity call them:
Store A located at www.storea.com
Store B located at www.storeb.com

Currently I have a bit of an issue with my product images and with the cache. When I add a new product to display on store B (so I enter the admin backend through Store A) the image is uploaded to storea.com/media/ etc. etc. but storeb.com is trying to find the image at storeb.com/media etc.

I tried changing the base_media_url for storeb.com to point to storea.com because all of it's images are being uploaded there, but now this is where the product image cache issue comes in. Store A isn't caching images for store B and so the images are still not found (so I'm in no better situation than before).

For example, storea.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1 (1 is the ID for storea.com) has all the images for Store A as you would expect, but storeb.com is trying to access files from the product image cache at storea.com/media/catalog/product/cache/2 (2 is the ID for storeb.com) but store A isn't caching image files for store B.

I know the images are being uploaded to storea.com/media because if I go one directory above the product image cache folder I can see all the 'uncached' versions of the images.

**TL;DR**
In short, I need a way to either:
**1:** Have the images I upload for Storeb.com (from the backend in storea.com) upload to storeb.com/media/catalog etc.  rather than storea.com/media/catalog

OR
**2** Make sure storea.com is able to cache ALL files in it's media/catalog/product folder and not just ones for its OWN store but for other stores as well.

Comment: Don't storea.com and storeb.com point to the exact same location in the filesystem of your server? So that storea.com/media/catalog is exactly the same as storeb.com/media/catalog?

Thats how I did this in my installation. Thre websites, three URLs, all in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure store B's media directory is a file system link to store a

something like

ln -s /path/to/storea/media ./media